# FabricJS | How to resize Fabric.Group if containing objects change size

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a Custom object (fabric.DefaultSensorGroup) which based on fabric.Group. This custom objects contains a fabric.Text and various number of other custom objects (fabric.DefaultSensor).

If I add/remove objects to the group, the "borders" of this group don't resize according to the containing objects.

**DefaultSensor:**

```
fabric.DefaultSensor = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {
    type : 'defaultSensor',

    initialize : function(options) {
        options || (options = {});

        // rect base
        var rectBase = new fabric.Rect({
            left : 0,
            top : 0,
            fill : options.sensorFillColor || '#aaf',
            width : 350,
            height : 30,
            stroke : '#000',
            strokeWidth : 1,
            rx : 5,
            ry : 5,
            shadow : 'rgba(0,0,0,1) 3px 3px 3px'
        });

        // text for sensor name and unit
        var nameUnitText = new fabric.Text('n/a', {
            left : 5,
            top : 2,
            fontSize : 20,
            fontFamily : 'Arial'
        });

        // text for sensor value
        var valueText = new fabric.Text('n/a', {
            top : 2,
            fontSize : 20,
            fontFamily : 'Arial',
        });

        this.callSuper('initialize', [ rectBase, nameUnitText, valueText ],
                options);

        this.set('sensorId', options.sensorId || '');
        this.set('sensorName', options.sensorName || 'n/a');
        this.set('sensorNameFontSize', options.sensorNameFontSize || 20);
        this.set('dataSeriesName', options.dataSeriesName || 'n/a');
        this.set('sensorUnit', options.sensorUnit || 'n/a');
        this.set('sensorValue', options.sensorValue || 'n/a');
        this.set('sensorFillColor', options.sensorFillColor || '#aaf');
        this.set('sensorDeviceId', options.sensorDeviceId || '');
        this.set('sensorProjectId', options.sensorProjectId || '');
        this.set('sensorDataSeriesId', options.sensorDataSeriesId || '');
        this.set('fractionalDigits', options.fractionalDigits || 2);
    },

    render : function(ctx, noTransform) {
        this.refreshSensorData();
        this.callSuper('render', ctx, noTransform);
    },

    refreshSensorData : function() {
        // set fill of base rect
        this.getObjects()[0].set('fill', this.get('sensorFillColor'));

        // set sensor name and unit text from current values
        this.getObjects()[1].set('text', this.get('dataSeriesName') + ' ['
                + this.get('sensorUnit') + ']');

        // set sensor name and unit text from current values
        this.getObjects()[1].set('fontSize', this.get('sensorNameFontSize'));

        // set sensor value text from current value
        this.getObjects()[2].set('text', this.get('sensorValue') + '');

        // set new width of base rect arcording to content width + 30 padding
        this.getObjects()[0].set('width', this.getObjects()[1].get('width')
                + this.getObjects()[2].get('width') + 30);

        // align base rect according to new width
        this.getObjects()[0].set('left', -1 * this.getObjects()[0].get('width')
                / 2);
        this.getObjects()[0].set('top', -1 * this.getObjects()[0].get('height')
                / 2);

        // adapt group width according to new content width
        this.set('width', this.getObjects()[0].get('width'));
        this.setCoords();

        // set new left of sensorlabel + 3 padding
        this.getObjects()[1].set('left', (-1 * (this.getObjects()[0]
                .get('width') / 2)) + 3);

        var topPadding = (this.getObjects()[0].get('height') - this
                .getObjects()[1].get('height')) / 2;
        this.getObjects()[1].set('top', (-1 * (this.getObjects()[0]
                .get('height') / 2))
                + topPadding);

        // position sensor value text according to the text width (right
        // aligned)
        this.getObjects()[2].set('left',
                (this.getObjects()[0].get('width') / 2)
                        - this.getObjects()[2].get('width') - 5);

    },

    toObject : function() {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
            sensorId : this.get('sensorId'),
            sensorName : this.get('sensorName'),
            sensorNameFontSize : this.get('sensorNameFontSize'),
            sensorContainerWidth : this.get('sensorContainerWidth'),
            dataSeriesName : this.get('dataSeriesName'),
            sensorUnit : this.get('sensorUnit'),
            sensorValue : this.get('sensorValue'),
            sensorFillColor : this.get('sensorFillColor'),
            sensorDeviceId : this.get('sensorDeviceId'),
            sensorProjectId : this.get('sensorProjectId'),
            sensorDataSeriesId : this.get('sensorDataSeriesId'),
            fractionalDigits : this.get('fractionalDigits')
        });
    },

    _render : function(ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    }
});

fabric.DefaultSensor.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects(object.objects, function(enlivenedObjects) {
        delete object.objects;
        callback && callback(new fabric.DefaultSensor(object));
    });
};

fabric.DefaultSensor.selected = function(object) {
    detailsbar.addColorSetter(object, 'sensorFillColor', webLU.gs(
            'label.Color', 'Color'));
    detailsbar.addOpacitySetter(object, 'opacity', webLU.gs('label.Opacity',
            'Opacity'));
    detailsbar.addSensorSelectSetter(object, webLU.gs('label.SensorSelection',
            'Sensor selection'));
    detailsbar.addDecimalPlacesSetter(object, 'fractionalDigits', webLU.gs(
            'label.DecimalPlaces', 'Decimal places'));
    detailsbar.addRangeSetter(object, 'sensorNameFontSize', webLU.gs(
            'label.SensorNameFontSize', 'Sensorname Font Size'), 10, 20);

};

fabric.DefaultSensor.async = true;
```

**DefaultSensorGroup:**

```
fabric.DefaultSensorGroup = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group,
{
    type : 'defaultSensorGroup',

    groupWidth: 40,

    groupHeight : 50,

    initialize : function(objects, options)
    {
        options || (options =
        {});

        var objectsExtended = this.buildGraphicObjects(objects)

        this.callSuper('initialize', objectsExtended, options);
        this.set('sensorGroupName', options.sensorGroupName || 'undefinedSensorGroup');
        this.set('sensorSelection', objects || []);
        this.set('fractionalDigits', options.fractionalDigits || 2);

    var blub = this.getObjects();
    for(var i in blub) {
        this.groupWidth = Math.max(this.groupWidth, blub[i].get('width'));
        this.groupHeight = Math.max(this.groupHeight, blub[i].get('height'));
    }

    this.setWidth(this.groupWidth);
        this.setHeight(this.groupHeight);
    },

    buildGraphicObjects : function(objects)
    {
        // rect base
        var rectBase = new fabric.Rect(
        {
            left : 0,
            top : 0,
            fill : '#C0C0C0',
            width : 370,
            height : 40 + (objects.length * 35),
            stroke : '#000',
            strokeWidth : 1,
            rx : 5,
            ry : 5,
            shadow : 'rgba(0,0,0,1) 3px 3px 3px'
        });

        // group name text
        var groupNameText = new fabric.Text('n/a',
        {
            left : 5,
            top : 0,
            fontSize : 20,
            textAlign : 'center',
            fontFamily : 'Arial'
        });

        var objectsExtended = [ groupNameText ];

        var sensorTopPosition = groupNameText.getHeight() + groupNameText.getLeft();

        // extend sensor group base objects (rect and group name text) with
        // sensor objects and set position of sensor objects
        if (objects)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
            {
                objectsExtended.push(objects[i].set(
                {
                    left : 10,
                    top : sensorTopPosition
                }));
                sensorTopPosition += objects[i].getHeight();
            }
        }

        return objectsExtended;
    },

    render : function(ctx, noTransform)
    {
        this.refreshGroupData();
        this.callSuper('render', ctx, noTransform);
    },

    refreshGroupData : function()
    {
        this.getObjects()[0].set('text', this.get('sensorGroupName'));
    },

    toObject : function()
    {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'),
        {
            sensorGroupName : this.get('sensorGroupName'),
            sensorSelection : this.get('sensorSelection'),
            fractionalDigits : this.get('fractionalDigits')
        });
    },

    addSensorToSelection : function(fabricSensor)
    {
        fabricSensor.set('fractionalDigits', this.get('fractionalDigits'));
        this.get('sensorSelection').push(fabricSensor);
        this.initialize(this.get('sensorSelection'), this.toObject());
    },

    removeSensorFromSelection : function(index)
    {
        this.get('sensorSelection').splice(index, 1);
        this.initialize(this.get('sensorSelection'), this.toObject());
    },

    _render : function(ctx)
    {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    }
});

fabric.DefaultSensorGroup.fromObject = function(object, callback)
{
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects(object.objects, function(enlivenedObjects)
    {
        delete object.objects;
        var sensors = [];
        if (object.sensorSelection)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < object.sensorSelection.length; i++)
            {
                sensors.push(new fabric.DefaultSensor(object.sensorSelection[i]).set('fractionalDigits', object.fractionalDigits));
            }
        }
        callback && callback(new fabric.DefaultSensorGroup(sensors, object));
    });
};

fabric.DefaultSensorGroup.selected = function(object)
{
    detailsbar.addTextSetter(object, 'sensorGroupName', webLU.gs('label.Name', 'Name'));
    detailsbar.addOpacitySetter(object, 'opacity', webLU.gs('label.Opacity', 'Opacity'));
    detailsbar.addSensorGroupSensorSelectionSetter(object, webLU.gs('label.SensorSelection', 'Sensor selection'));
    detailsbar.addDecimalPlacesSetter(object, 'fractionalDigits', webLU.gs('label.DecimalPlaces', 'Decimal places'));
};

fabric.DefaultSensorGroup.async = true;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you add your objects, do you add them with group.add() or group.addWithUpdate()?

Becase the add function just throws them into the group without recalculating the new border size. But with group.addWithUpdate() it recalculats the size of the bounding box of the group.